# How can I store wonton wrappers in the freezer?

Tags: substitutions, pasta, storage

I have found that authentic frozen egg roll wrappers from an Asian food store work well for canneloni and ravioli. Just thaw, fill, and roll. You can cut them to any desired length. Also, frozen wonton wrappers work exceptionally well for ravioli. While I haven't tried it yet the wonton wrappers should be ideal for tortellini/tortelloni.

But I don't always have these on hand and the nearest place I can get them is about 30 miles away. I have tried buying extra and keeping them frozen but they seem to get freezer burned quickly, with the edges being too dry and brittle to use.

I'm wondering if anyone has any tips on how to keep them better. Or does anyone have any other alternatives that would be as easy to use?

Comment: Cannelloni _can_ be crepes. Pasta cannelloni are just as common.

Comment: Have you tried thawing them in the fridge?  I've had refrigerated ones that last for weeks in the fridge if you don't open the package.

Comment: Comments removed - the question seems all sorted out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to have watched a TV show the other day about this very problem and they suggested making a big batch of whatever filling or fillings you are thinking of using (presently or in the future) and go ahead and make them all up and freeze them ready to cook.  They were making several kinds of ravioli that day.  They made them all up and placed them on cookie sheets to freeze and then placed them in ZipLock bags and they had a nice supply to pull out of the freezer whenever they were ready to cook them.  They didn't have a problem with brittle wontons once they were filled.  They used beaten egg to seal the edges so the filling wouldn't ooze out.  You can use this same method for any shape or filling....doesn't have to be ravioli, of course.

Comment: Hi Nancy, welcome to the site and thanks for your answer. Look [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) to get a better feel for the site. +1 for a good answer. Someone will probably come along and edit out your signature, just because we don't do that here, but the substance of your answer is helpful and just the kind of thing we want here.

Answer (score 2):

Freezer burn is due to water [sublimating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition)) out of food, in this case wonton wrappers.  The process usually becomes apparent after two weeks of being frozen.

This is a tough process to stop, but it can be slowed down by not giving the water anywhere else to go.

Ways to do this remove all air space around the food before freezing by either:
1. packaging in vacuum sealer bags
2. tightly sealing in and removing all air from a zip lock type freezer bag, avoid the ones with sliders
3. tightly wrapping in cling wrap, then tape or put in a normal plastic baggie to keep the cling wrap from coming apart

Answer (score -1):

How about putting them in a freezer bag full of water ,then put them in the freezer.Works well for freezing fish.

Comment: Probably not the wisest route for flour-based items like egg roll wrappers. Might be a good idea for fish, though.